# Java function to sort string recursively

Tags: java, string, sorting, recursion

So I'm trying to write a function that sorts a string alphabetically.
Here is what I've done:

```
public static String stringSort(String s) {
    if(s.length()<2) {
        return s;
    }
    String recursion = stringSort(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
    recursion += s.substring(recursion.length()); 
    if(recursion.charAt(recursion.length()-2)<recursion.charAt(recursion.length()-1)) {
        return recursion;
    }
    char a = recursion.charAt(recursion.length()-2);
    char b = recursion.charAt(recursion.length()-1);
    if(recursion.length()>2) {
        recursion = recursion.substring(0, recursion.length()-2)+b+a;
    } else {
        recursion = ""+b+a;
    }
    String recursion2 = stringSort(recursion);
    return recursion2;
}
```

Basically, it checks the first two letters, swaps if needed and checks again or it continues to check the next two letters.

It seems to work for some words (I tried man and superman), but I get a stack overflow error for other words (splendid). Is there a more efficient way of doing this so I don't get stack overflow?

Comment: this is supposed to be like a helper function for checking if two strings are anagrams of each other through recursion. I thought it'd be easier to sort the strings first and then recursively check if they match up, if they do then the two strings would be anagrams. If there's a better way to do anagrams function, please let me know too.

Comment: If your goal is to simply sort a String, you could use `String sortedString = new String(Arrays.sort(str.toCharArray()));` where `str` is your actual String.

Comment: if you want to do it on your own, you still should work with a `char[]` instead of creating new strings over and over again. Next step: search a proper sorting algorithm and implement that. You can do that on [Wikipedia: Sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) (or for more fun you can find one of the funny explanation with dances video playlists on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdIKIf9mHk0&list=PLOmdoKois7_FK-ySGwHBkltzB11snW7KQ) )